# Fourier transform of characteristic function in a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

A similar question was asked before for an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. I wonder how to do it for a characteristic function of $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|<r\}$ i.e. I want to calculate $$ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}} \chi_{|x|<r}(x)\exp(-ikx) dx.$$ Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you work with euclidian norm?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo yes, it is euclidian norm.

Comment: Have you tried with spherical coordinates?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo thank you for your advise. Does it make sense switch to spherical coordinates? Evantually, I should calculate $\int_{|x|<r} exp(-ikx)dx$ and $|x|<r$ represents here a sphere centered $(0,0,0)$.Could you please give me a clue, how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the $z$ axis along $k$ and denoting $|k|$ by $q$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^3}\chi_{|x|\lt r}(x)\exp(-\mathrm ikx)\,\mathrm dx
&=\int_0^r R^2\,\mathrm dR\int_0^\pi\sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi\exp(-\mathrm iqR\cos\theta)
\\
&=2\pi\int_0^r R^2\,\mathrm dR\int_0^\pi\sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\exp(-\mathrm iqR\cos\theta)
\\
&=2\pi\int_0^r R^2\,\mathrm dR\left[\frac1{\mathrm iqR}\exp(-\mathrm iqR\cos\theta)\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}
\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\mathrm iq}\int_0^r \mathrm dRR\left(\exp(\mathrm iqR)-\exp(-\mathrm iqR)\right)
\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{q^3}\left(r\cos qr-\sin qr\right)\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @pcepkin: You're welcome.

Comment: I think this is wrong? $r\cos qr−\sin qr$ do not have the same units. I think the answer is $\frac{4 \pi}{k^3}  (\sin (k R)-k R \cos (k R))$

Comment: The characteristic function of an $n$-ball can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423733/claims-and-questions-regarding-n-ball-distribution.